# Navigating to a page by calling it's PageObject

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm writing some selenium tests and wondering how can i navigate say to my ProfilePage, just by calling it's class in my test
So i got my BasePage class,

```
class BasePage(object):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver  
        self._validate_page(driver)

    @abstractclassmethod
    def _validate_page(self,driver):
        return

class PageNotDisplayedException(Exception):
 """throw this exception when page was not displayed, or different page is displayed""" 
       pass
```

my BaseTestCase class

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        self.driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')

    def navigateTo(self, to):
        self.driver.get(to)

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

and my smoketest. In my smoketest i'd like to put something like  navigateTo(ProfilePage) wihtout test directly calling to webdriver.

```
class SmokeTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        LoginPage(self.driver).login(self.driver)
        navigateTo(self.ProfilePage)
```

and my ProfilePage :

```
class ProfilePage(BasePage):

    _page_id = ".//[@class='profile']"
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/my.profile"

    def __init__(self,driver):
        super(ProfilePage, self).__init__(driver)

    def _validate_page(self, driver):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(self._page_id)
        except: 
            raise PageNotDisplayedException
            ("Profile Page could not be displayed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProfilePage` page object class should have a `url` property associated with the page:

```
class ProfilePage(BasePage):
     url = "https://my.url/profile"
```

Then, `navigateTo` method should use this property:

```
def navigateTo(self, page):
    self.driver.get(page.url)
```

And, then, you should call `self.navigateTo` in your test:

```
class SmokeTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        LoginPage(self.driver).login(self.driver)

        profilePage = ProfilePage(self.driver)
        self.navigateTo(profilePage)
```

Comment: Getting  self.navigateTo(self.ProfilePage) 
AttributeError: 'SmokeTest' object has no attribute 'ProfilePage' :(

Comment: @EugeneNosenko sorry, I assumed you've previously set the `ProfilePage`.

Comment: @EugeneNosenko could you post the code where you define the `ProfilePage`? Thanks.

Comment: yep i set the profilepage and imported it, but eclipse is showing me unused import alert

Comment: @EugeneNosenko okay, updated - is it what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: yep, works as a charm. I guess it makes sense :) still learning python, thanks